# Coefficients in discrete proportional hazards model

Tags: regression-coefficients, proportional-hazards, discrete-time

I am aware of the rationale behind taking the exponentiated coefficients in a proportional hazards model as representing change in hazard per unit change in the corresponding predictor. This also implies that it should be possible to obtain a hazard greater than 1. However, with the inverse of the cloglog link function being $1-e^{-e^{\nu}}$, it doesn't seem possible for the hazard to actually exceed 1. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have discrete or continuous time models?  In discrete time, you model probability to leave the state, and that is obviously < 1.  In continuous time you model the exit rate, and usually you parametrize the hazard rate as $\theta(x, t) = \exp(\beta' x) \cdot \phi(t)$.  This can be > 1.  I don't understand the link function in this context.

Comment: I have a model in discrete time. The dependent variable for each subject is zero until either they are censored - thus being coded zero in their final entry - or experience the event - thus being coded 1. This yields a binary response variable, to which I am fitting a binomial regression model with the cloglog link function in line with recommendations (eg Singer & WIllett, 2003) for data that occurs in continuous time but is available at discrete points.

Comment: PS Happy to be referred to an existing answer. I have tried my best to find one, but they seem to be mostly about the continuous-time case.

Comment: Damned, I think I answered yesterday...

Answer (score 0):

In continuous time *hazard rate* is the exit probability per unit time (given still in the initial state).  It may exceed one.  In discrete time, you look at *probability to exit during the time interval*, and obviously, as a probability, it must be $\le 1$.  I think you have to be clear of this distinction to understand the problem.

It seems to me that you model the (continuous time) hazard rate as $e^\nu$ (constant in time).  In this case the probability to have exited the initial state by $t$ is $Pr(T < t) = 1 -  e^{-e^\nu t}$ (this is exponential CDF).  If your hazard rate is not constant, you will have an integral instead of $-e^\nu t$.

Sorry, I am not quite familiar what role does the link function play in your specification.